# Make a link to a url start up my app and not open embedded

Tags: android

I defined the following intent filter in my application in order to make it respond to url links.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="http"/>
            <data android:scheme="https"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Now when I click a link in an external app (from example a link sent by sms) it opens my app in an embedded way in the current application. Meaning that if I go to background I see my app inside the sms application.
I want the link to make my application to be opened separately. This is the correct behaviour, and happens for example when choosing chrome/ android native browser as the app to open the link.

Is there a way to change that for my app as well?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `launchMode` of your activity to `singleTask` or `singleInstance`. This will force the system to open a new task for your app instead of opening it in the same task as the sms-app or whatever.

It should look somehow like this:

```
<activity android:name="yourActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>
```

For more information, see the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: I don't want to change the application's launch mode. Checked several known browsers manifest, and saw they use the regular launch mode. however,the link still opens their app in a new process, and not embedded